a question on Z-graded rings and Z-graded modules from Hal Schenck's book

I have a question regarding Z-graded rings/modules from the book that i am currently reading which is:
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-06664-1
My question is around the definition of R(i) in the last line.

First since the definition of R(i) involves "degree", am i correct in assuming that here it is assumed that R = K[x] (although it is not explicitly mentioned so and the definition seems general)

Assuming as in question 1 that R = K[x], how can the degree be "-i" - a negative number? Isn't the degree of a polynomial in K[x] always supposed to be non-negative?


Any help on this is much appreciated!

For (1) the book is not assuming that $R = k[x]$. If $R$ has a $\mathbb Z$-grading $\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb Z} R_i$, then any element in $R_i$ is said to have degree $i$.
The bottom paragraph is introducing "twists", which "shift" the degree of $R$ by $i$. This might seem pointless because $R(i)$ and $R$ are essentially the same object, but it is done sometimes so that maps between them preserve degree. For example, if $R=k[x]$, the map $R(-2)\to R$ multiplying an element by $x^2$ is degree preserving, since e.g. $1$ now has degree $2$. You see this often with free resolutions.

Please don’t answer questions in comments. Consider converting your comment into an answer. @PhilipSpeegle

@PhilipSpeegle, I found this alternate definition in a document which makes it muc easier to understand.
Let $M = \bigoplus_{i\in G}M_i$ be a graded over R = $\bigoplus_{i\in G}R_i$. Let  $\alpha \in G$. Then $M(\alpha)$ is the graded R-module with the property that  $M(\alpha){i} = M{i+\alpha}$
How does it apply to our situation? Since R is itself an R-module over itself, so the equation also holds for R: $R(\alpha){i} = R{i+\alpha}$
Thanks for your explanation about the twists. It is clear now.
